# How to correctly handle emojies entry into mysql database?

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc, mysql-workbench

I send emojies from an android app to my server, everything works as intended up until entering the emojies to mysql databse. Here is the Error Log. I am using characterEncoding=UTF-8 with the url that I am connecting to the databse.
I have read that if you set up characterEncoding to utf8m4 it will work I have tried that as well and it does not work

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x8E\x93' for column 'clear_text' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1192)
    at Signup.postAreply(Signup.java:978)
    at Signup.doPost(Signup.java:291)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:184)
    at GetThem.doFilter(GetThem.java:17)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:184)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:184)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:361)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1080)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:75)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:757)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Define "does not work". And by the way, that is "utf8-mb4". MySQL has had a flawed conception of Unicode for a long time that it had to define this "encoding" in order to allow code points outside the BMP to be stored reliably... But really: drop MySQL. Use PostgreSQL. Problem(s) solved.

Comment: If stop using mysql will I have to create the database all over again because it contains data, also changing to the one you mentioned will all the problem dealing with encoding be resolved

Comment: Also is there a workbench for PostgreSQL like MySQL?